# python script works in spyder console but not in spyder ipython or cmd in windows

Tags: cmd, windows-10, command-line-interface, spyder

I am trying to run this python script from [How to connect to TT X_TRADER API in order to create an automated trading system using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656579/how-to-connect-to-tt-x-trader-api-in-order-to-create-an-automated-trading-system)

```
import pythoncom
from time import sleep
from win32com.client import Dispatch, DispatchWithEvents, getevents
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch, EnsureModule

GATE = None
NOTIFY = None

class InstrNotify(getevents('XTAPI.TTInstrNotify')):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Subscribe(self, pInstr):
        self.AttachInstrument(pInstr)
        pInstr.Open(0)

    def OnNotifyFound(self, pNotify=None, pInstr=None):
        pInstr = Dispatch(pInstr)        
        print 'Found instrument:'
        print '--> Contract: %s' % pInstr.Get('Contract')
        print '--> Exchange: %s' % pInstr.Get('Exchange')

    def OnNotifyNotFound(self, pNotify=None, pInstr=None):
        pInstr = Dispatch(pInstr)        
        print 'Unable to find instrument'

    def OnNotifyUpdate(self, pNotify=None, pInstr=None):
        pInstr = Dispatch(pInstr)
        contract = pInstr.Get('Contract')

        bid = pInstr.Get('Bid')
        ask = pInstr.Get('Ask')
        last = pInstr.Get('Last')

        print '[UPDATE] %s: %s/%s' % (contract, bid, ask)


def Connect():
    global NOTIFY, GATE
    #the below is required in order to establish the com-object links
    #that way you don't need to run makepy first
    EnsureModule('{98B8AE14-466F-11D6-A27B-00B0D0F3CCA6}', 0, 1, 0)

    GATE = EnsureDispatch('XTAPI.TTGate')
    NOTIFY = DispatchWithEvents('XTAPI.TTInstrNotify', InstrNotify) 


def main():
    Connect()

    pInstr = EnsureDispatch('XTAPI.TTInstrObj')
    pInstr.Exchange = 'CME-A'
    pInstr.Product  = 'CL'
    pInstr.Contract = 'CL Mar13'
    pInstr.ProdType = 'FUTURE'

    NOTIFY.Subscribe(pInstr)

    for i in range(10):
        pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
        sleep(1.0)
```

I made one adjustment which was on line 9:

```
class InstrNotify(getevents('XTAPI.TTInstrNotify')):
```

to:

```
class InstrNotify():
```

in order to make it work (still not too sure why it works like that, but I think its because there is ...'no need to use getevents as DispatchWithevents already does the getevents, so just defining your Events class without a base-class should work.'(from win32 documentation, but I still not sure what it means, hope someone here will be kind enough to explain it too).

Anyway, my main question here is that while I can make this script work in spyder  python console, I cannot make it work in the spyder ipython console nor in the cmd console ( windows command line). And I cannot figure out why, nor find the answer anywhere. I sincerely hope someone here will be kind enough to help. Thanks so much in advance.

btw, i am using python 3.6.0, Anaconda 4.3.0 (64bit), on windows 10 (64 bit). in the windows cmd, also using the same conda environment as the spyder.